# String Unicode remove char from the string

Tags: java, string, format

I have a string formatted with NumberFormat instance.  When i display the chars of the string i have a non-breaking space (hexa code : A0 and unicode 160).  How can i remove this character from my string.
I tried `string = string.replaceAll("\u0160", "");` and `string = string.replaceAll("0xA0", "")`, both didn't work.

```
String string = ((JTextField)c)getText();
string = string.replace("\u0160", "");
System.out.println("string : " string);

for(int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
System.out.print("char : " + string.charAt(i));
System.out.printf("Decimal value %d", (int)string.charAt(i));
System.out.println("Code point : " + Character.codePointAt(string, i));
}
```

The output still contains a white space with decimal value 160 and code point 160.

Comment: Please post a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. Your first approach should be fine, although I'd use `replace` rather than `replaceAll`, as you really don't need a regex here.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The unicode character `\u0160` is not a non-breaking space. After the \u there must be the hexadecimal representation of the character not the decimal, so the unicode for non-breaking space is `\u00A0`. Try using:

```
string = string.replace("\u00A0","");
```

Comment: You can also use replace(char, char) instead of replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) like this string  = string.replace('\u00A0', Character.MIN_VALUE)

Answer (score 4):

```
String string = "89774lf&933 k880990";

string = string.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );

System.out.println(string);
```

OUTPUT:

```
89774933880990
```

It will eliminate all the `char` other than `digits`.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't work when i try to use replace or replaceAll ?

Answer (score 2):

This is working as is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "hi\u0160bye";
    System.out.println(string);
    string = string.replaceAll("\u0160", "");
    System.out.println(string);
}
```